# R: Can you make my ugly text concacting function pretty

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am trying to write a function what makes R interpret arguments without evaluating them and pushes them into a new string.

This is what I have so far.  It is very ugly but works for up to 5:

```
pl <- pasteliteral <- 
function(v1='',v2='',v3='',v4='',v5='', sep="") {

 stopifnot(v1!="")

 # Sort up to 10 values
 if (deparse(substitute(v1)!=""))  {s<-deparse(substitute(v1))
 if (deparse(substitute(v2)!=""))  {s<-paste(s, deparse(substitute(v2)), sep=sep)
 if (deparse(substitute(v3)!=""))  {s<-paste(s, deparse(substitute(v3)), sep=sep)
 if (deparse(substitute(v4)!=""))  {s<-paste(s, deparse(substitute(v4)), sep=sep)
 if (deparse(substitute(v5)!=""))  {s<-paste(s, deparse(substitute(v5)), sep=sep)
 }}}}}
 s
}

pl(1,2,3,a,hello)
[1] "123ahello"
```

Comment: And I know there is no possible usage for this function except once I have it I will modify it to check each argument which is a character to see if it exists and if it does I will paste them together.

Comment: You could collect your arguments with `as.list(substitute(list(1,2,3,a,hello)))[-1]` and then `lapply` `deparse` and `do.call` `paste`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `sys.call`:

```
pl <- pasteliteral <- function(..., sep="") {
  ## remove first element (the function name)
  ca <- sys.call()[-1]

  ## remove last element if it is sep     
  if (ca[[length(ca)]] == sep) {
    ca <- ca[-length(ca)]
  }
  paste0(ca, collapse=sep)
}

pl(1,2,3,a,hello)
# [1] "123ahello"

pl(1,2,3,a,hello, sep=":")
# [1] "1:2:3:a:hello"
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  Is there any chance you could show me how to make the `ca` "language" object into a vector now?

Comment: @fsmart: Do you mean e.g. `as.character(ca)`?