# R: Return function call as string unevaluated

Tags: r, function, arguments

I would very much like to be able to have the ability to fully manipulate, parse, and do whatever I want with the arguments of a function.  I think the best way to accomplish this would be a function which turned `...` into a string.  Something like:

```
f(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1) 
[1] "f(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1)"
```

But really this is not what I want end because I want to be able to embed this into another function:

```
g <- function(...) callstr(...)
g(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1) 
[1] "g(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1)"
```

Comment: An alternative might be to use `body()` to manipulate the interior of the function and "rebuild" it as desired before calling the newly-modded function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nearly the same answer as in your question yesterday [R: Can you make my ugly text concacting function pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031516/r-can-you-make-my-ugly-text-concacting-function-pretty#23031704): Use `sys.call` and `deparse`.

```
g <- function(...)deparse(sys.call())

g(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1)
# [1] "g(345, x = 234, randomcharacters() + 34 - 321 == 1)"
```

Comment: Thank you but it is different.  Unfortunately, I realized my question from yesterday did not get me to where I needed to go because the `sys.call()` needs to be called from within a nested function.  Perhaps by changing the environment?  See the problem `f <- function(...) g(...) ; f(345,x=234,randomcharacters()+34-321==1); [1] "g(...)"`

Comment: @fsmart: `g <- function(...)deparse(sys.call(-1))`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. You don't know how much time I am spending going in circles with this stuff.

Comment: `match.call()` is likely to be better, and you're unlikely to actually want to turn this into a string. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html for more details.